# Generating Many Random Simulations with PyCUDA + CURAND

Tags: pycuda

For numDraws up to 100000 (1M), I can do the following easily

```
def Simple_Elt(numDraws):
    import numpy as np
    gauss = np.random.normal

    import pycuda.gpuarray as ga
    from pycuda.cumath import exp as gaexp    
    import pycuda.autoinit
    from pycuda.elementwise import ElementwiseKernel

    npgausses = gauss(size=(numDraws,)).astype(np.float32)
    gausses   = ga.to_gpu(npgausses)

    eltComp = """p[i] = exp(p[i]);"""
    kernel = ElementwiseKernel("float *p", eltComp, "expnorm")
    kernel(gausses)

    sumEN = ga.sum(gausses).get()

Simple_Elt(1000000)
```

However, for N = 10000000 (10M), I run out of GPU memory when transferring the random values to the GPU.  I'd like to possibly solve two problems at one time:  (1) efficiently use the GPU to generate the random numbers and (2) remove the size limitation.

Now, I'm not sure the best way to do it.  Code [here](http://statisfaction.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/playing-with-pycuda-faster-generation-of-normal-variables/) shows how to make a custom normal random number generator using "raw" PyCUDA to do Box-Muller from CPU generated uniform randoms, but I think it would make more sense to use CURAND.  However, using PyCuda's CURAND interface seems to give me the same size limitations (and, I believe it makes many random number generators which causes high overhead -- that's from the PyCUDA CURAND API document warning [here](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html#module-pycuda.curandom).  So, I suppose a possibility is to use PyCUDA with custom calls to underlying CURAND.  This is all guess work.

But, my real question is the best way to solve the two issues above.

Examples, pointers, and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: What GPU are you running this on?

Comment: Old NVIDIA.  lspci says: NVIDIA Corporation C77 [GeForce 8300] (rev a2).